# Azure Logic App fires twice when triggered

Tags: c#

Both my Azure Logic App jobs they are fired twice when run.
So, at present I have to create logic to prevent this.

Why do they fire twice, and how can I avoid it ?

Regards

Guttorm Haaversen

Comment: how do you know its getting fired twice because of logs you are saying ? if yes see this :https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1431

Comment: In the activity log, I can see the same process twice. So, no it is not Rahul's suggestion. The same process is triggered twice.